# Java ExecutorService Infinite Loop Job

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to write daemon service job in java. This service will run for every minute.

But I cannot implement this by using ExecutorService and I don't know if this is correct way. Below is my code snippet:

```
public void startService() {
    try {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        for (;;) {
            service.submit(new Service1()); // this will send some set of emails
            service.submit(new Service2()); // this will send some set of emails
            service.submit(new Service3()); // this will send some set of sms
        }
        service.shutdown(); // It says Unreachable code so when should i shutdown the service
        service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to look at [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and its implementations. This service allows you to schedule the jobs to run with pre-defined frequency. This is the short answer. As for implementation details there are too many unknowns to give you practical advice. Do you want your program to run in a container (Web or Application Server) or as Standalone with domain thread? are you running on Unix/Linux (So the Cron job scheduler can be used) or Windows? One of the scheduler options could be [quartz-scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your [`for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) does not have an **ending condition**: `for(;;)`, and no break statement.

So all the code **after** this loop is if course **unreachable**.

---

You have to wait 1 minute **inside the loop**, not after (as the code after your looping will never be runned).

Keeping your synthax, I guess it should be:

```
for (;;) {
    service.submit(new Service1()); // this will send some set of emails
    service.submit(new Service2()); // this will send some set of emails
    service.submit(new Service3()); // this will send some set of sms
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is not ending job. it will run every minute. Can you please say how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This here:

```
for (;;) {
        service.submit(new Service1()); // this will send some set of emails
        service.submit(new Service2()); // this will send some set of emails
        service.submit(new Service3()); // this will send some set of sms
    }
```

Is an infinite loop; it keeps submitting new jobs into your threadpool ... constantly. Not **once** per minute, but **once** per iteration. You have to **slow** down your loop!

I am not sure what you are asking for, but you should either simply remove that loop-construct; or more likely, do something like:

```
while (true) {
  service.submit(new Service1()); // this will send some set of emails
  service.submit(new Service2()); // this will send some set of emails
  service.submit(new Service3()); // this will send some set of sms
  Thread.sleep( 1 minute );
}
```

or something alike.